# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.put

Tags: java, android, json

I'm developing an Android library, i add my lib in my Test project, now i have a error that can't allow to finish my test:

```
Could not find method org.json.JSONObject.put, referenced from method com.ldm.JsonBuilder.jsonbuilder

Process: , PID: 31181
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.put
at com.ldm.JsonBuilder.jsonbuilder(JsonBuilder.java:70)
at com.ldm.TestConnection.TestNow(TestConnection.java:79)
at ldm.eisworld.it.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/json.jar')
    compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

And this is a part of my code:

```
   /* Parsing of hash map */
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> tr : rh.entrySet()) {

        try {
            /* Object that contains URL */
            JSONObject TraceUrl = new JSONObject();
            /* Object that contains nodes for each URL */
            JSONObject TraceNodes = new JSONObject();

            TraceUrl.put("url", tr.getKey());
            TraceUrl.put("nodes", tr.getValue());
            trace.put(TraceUrl);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
```

How i can resolve it ?

Comment: post your tr object where you set the values please

Comment: Looks like incompatible classes

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be importing some kind of external json library that doesn't have a `put()` method.

JSONObject that has `put()` is "built in" to android, you don't need any additional libraries for it.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("key", "value");
```

This will work.

Comment: I have imported a external library because in the process of exportation of my jar I have a problem with JSON function (cannot resolve Json...)

Comment: @Max, well, the library you use does not support `put()` method on the json object. You can either use the builtin json library like I showed, or find a corresponding method for put() in your external library

Comment: Ok, how i can resove this problem ?

Comment: I don't undestard, if i wrote a class in Android app all my code work perfectlym but If i create a java lib does't work because "JSON* cannot resolve  symbol"

Answer (score 1):

**KOTLIN**
Late but, i think it might help someone.
i had this error

```
No virtual method put(Ljava/lang/String;F)Lorg/json/JSONObject; in class Lorg/json/JSONObject
```

i was importing the correct class and not importing any other related 3rd party libs.  even added progaurd rules but nothing helped.

then i replaced

```
                val orderRequest = JSONObject()
                orderRequest.put("amount", amount)
                orderRequest.put("currency", "INR")
                orderRequest.put("receipt", "order_rcptid_11")
```

with

```
         val reqStr = """
                    {
                    "amount" : "$amount",
                    "currency" : "INR",
                    "receipt" : "order_rcptid_11"
                    }
                    """.trimIndent()
                
         val orderRequest = JSONObject(reqStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), the `Object` value passed to `JSONObject.put` must be:

> ...a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, NULL, or null. May not be NaNs or infinities.

`tr.getValue()` is of type `ArrayList<String>`. Since this is not one of the listed types, the attempt fails at runtime.